# Accessing and filtering an array much more efficiently in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, performance, processing-efficiency

I wrote a code to filter an json array and print some elements, but it caused a banishment for me for too much cpu usage (free hosting plan)
can you help me make it more efficient? perhaps by using functions like array_filter
here is my code:

```
$obj = json_decode($data,true);
$elements=count($obj)-1;
for ($x = 0; $x <= $elements; $x++){
  if ($obj[$x]["SymbolStateId"]==1)  {
  echo $obj[$x]["FirstOrderPage"]["ExchangeSymbols"]["NSCCode"];
  echo ",";
  echo $obj[$x]["FirstOrderPage"]["BestBuyPrice"];
  echo ";";

  }
}
```

Comment: You should post incomimg data ($data) and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) + [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

**array_filter** let you to filter the array elements and returns a new array with elements that satisfy the callback boolean statement.

**array_walk** in the other hand lets you to iterate each array element and apply a *callback* function for each of that

Please, use [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) operator to print more variables, don't make 3 statements for printing a string

```
array_walk(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        function($item) {
            return $item["SymbolStateId"] == 1;
        }
    ),
    function($item) {
        echo $item["FirstOrderPage"]["ExchangeSymbols"]["NSCCode"] . "," . $item["FirstOrderPage"]["BestBuyPrice"] . ";";
    },
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! but how I can find out how efficient it is? I use microtime(true) to both codes and run times are almost equal!